# How to show / hide a colorpicker attached to jQuery slider handle

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, slider, uislider, color-picker

I want to achieve this :

1. show the picker on clicking jQuery slider handle
2. the picker is to be shown adjacent to the current position of slider
3. hide the picker on clicking anything other than slider handle
   I want to use this [colorpicker](http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum/).
   I tried it at my own. I succeeded in showing the colorpicker but failed to hide it.

My code is as follows :

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").click(function(e){
    $("#colorpickerDiv").css({"left":e.pageX,"top":e.pageY});
    $("#colorpickerDiv").spectrum("show");
});
$("body").click(function(){
    $("#colorpickerDiv").spectrum("hide");
});
```

Comment: I found my answer in this question.. thanks.. :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author of the plugin here.

Here is a working example of what I think you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/FLBQW/.  Your problem may have been caused by an issue from an earlier version, but if you are still having problems and can post a test case on jsFiddle, we should be able to figure it out.

Comment: In this code the colorpicker only shows up when the slider handle is moved to another position. If you click right in the middle of handle thus keeping the handle unmoved , the picker doesnt show up.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really sure what you were asking for.  This example might be more like what you were asking: http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/FLBQW/9/

Comment: that works great... how about hiding the permanent small box adjacent to the picker